# Why does Devise timedout? take a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to make sense of the Devise **[source code for the timeoutable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/timeoutable.rb).** I'm really confused as to what's going on with the `timedout?` method.

Intuitively, you should be able to call `user.timedout?` without any parameters and it will return true if the user's session has timed out, false if not. Can someone explain what this parameter is doing?

**Edit:**
Ok, so it seems like this method is only able to check if a user has timed out if you *already know their last access time*. I guess my next question would be: what is the cleanest way to check if a different user has timed out? (not current_user). That is, how can I call `timedout?` in the way specified above, with no parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise will use Warden to store the last request time (not last signed_in_time). See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb

So if you want to duplicate this functionality, you'll need to store the last_request_time in the database and update it with each request (in an after_filter in application_controller).

Once that's there, you could add this method to the user, and use it to delegate to the devise timedout? method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable, :trackable #etc

  def expired?
    valid_until = last_access_time + 30.minutes
    timedout?(valid_until)
  end

end
```

then if you have a user:

```
user.expired?
```

Comment: Yeah... I figured I would have to do something like this... unfortunately.